# WSO identity server , service provider creation with permissions does not work

Tags: permissions, wso2

I got following exception while creating new service provider with permissions , following is some portion of its code.

```
iManagementServiceStub = new IdentityApplicationManagementServiceStub();
iManagementServiceStub.createApplication(createApplication);
```

Following is exception i am getting on client side.

> identity.IdentityApplicationManagementServiceIdentityApplicationManagementException: Error while storing permissions for application sp3
>   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
>   at identity.IdentityApplicationManagementServiceStub.createApplication(IdentityApplicationManagementServiceStub.java:1007)
>   at identity.AddServiceProvider.main(AddServiceProvider.java:92)

Following are exception on server side.

> Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: The path '/_system/governance/permission/applications/sp3/org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.common.model.ApplicationPermission@12809798' contains one or more illegal characters (~!@#;%^*()+={}|\<>"',)
>   at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.Repository.put(Repository.java:262)
>   at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.put(EmbeddedRegistry.java:717)
>   at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.caching.CacheBackedRegistry.put(CacheBackedRegistry.java:591)
>   at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.putInternal(UserRegistry.java:828)
>   at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.putInternal(UserRegistry.java:796)
>   at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.access$900(UserRegistry.java:61)
>   at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$10.run(UserRegistry.java:786)
>   at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$10.run(UserRegistry.java:783)
>   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>   at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.put(UserRegistry.java:783)
>   at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.mgt.ApplicationMgtUtil.storePermissions(ApplicationMgtUtil.java:299)
>   ... 64 more

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

When analyzing the error log, you can see that there are illegal charactors in your permission.

```
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: The path '/_system/governance/permission/applications/sp3/org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.common.model.ApplicationPermission@12809798' contains one or more illegal characters (~!@#;%^*()+={}|\<>"',)
```

Please check the permission name. Basically those charactors are reserved and have an specific use. So you cannot use them elsewhere whithout encoding them[1].

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding